# How to get proper syntax highlighting for member variables and functions?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have the following C++ code snippet colored using the default Light+ theme:

[image]

To achieve it, all I needed to add to settings was

```
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "textMateRules": [
            {
                "scope": "variable.other.local",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#0000FF",
                    "fontStyle": "italic bold underline"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
```

Local variables are black, member variables are dark blue, and member functions are dark gold. Even in a chain of calling, member variables and member functions are highlighted appropriately.

However, I wanted to use the [OneHalf Light](https://github.com/sonph/onehalf/tree/master/vscode) theme. When I enable it with the same setting as above, I get the following:

[image]

The member variable in the class itself is uncolored, member and local variables are colored the same, and the declaration of local variables is uncolored. Only member functions are appropriately colored.

For some reason, the `variable.other.local` property is ignored.

Here is the closest I can get:

```
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "textMateRules": [
            {
                "scope": "variable.other",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#0000FF",
                    "fontStyle": "italic bold underline"
                }
            },
            {
                "scope": "variable.other.local",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#FF00FF",
                    "fontStyle": "italic bold underline"
                }
            },
            {
                "scope": "variable.other.property",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#FF0000",
                    "fontStyle": "italic bold underline"
                }
            },
            {
                "scope": "entity.name.function",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#00CC00",
                    "fontStyle": "italic bold underline"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

Those configurations give me this:

[image]

So:

1. `entity.name.function` seems to work correctly.
2. `variable.other.local` is completely ignored.
3. LHS usages of `foo` are captured by `variable.other`, but declarations are RHS usages are not.
4. `bar` in the class definition is ignored by `variable.other.property`.
5. If `.bar` is the last thing in a line, it is correctly colored by `variable.other.property`.
6. If `.bar` is in the middle of a line, it is ignored by `variable.other.property` and colored using `variable.other`.

For the sake of comparison, here is what those same rules look like using the Light+ theme:

[image]

It works exactly as expected!

Why would `variable.other.local` work for one theme but not another? It's my understanding that VS Code simply labels all words with a type and a theme simply decides what color each type should be. Is the theme somehow using a different syntax engine?